# How to get cellular network quality in React Native / Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, cellular-network

I have an Expo app that uses Firebase to send SMS verification to users. Unfortunetely, in some cases, users doesn't receive SMS. I know that sometimes, this is because users are in a location without cellular network (but they can have wifi).

So I wan't to warn users when they are in a place without cellular network.

I found [NetInfo](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/netinfo/) module to get info about internet connection, but this is not what I want.

I also found [Cellular](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/cellular/) module. I can get informations about carrier name, cellular generation, etc, but not about the cellular network quality.

Please, how can I get cellular network quality to know if users can receive SMS or not?